# How do I automatically accept EULA for MS ODBC for unix with Ansible?

Tags: ansible, centos7, eula, msodbcsql17

I have a playbook that updates our Linux servers.  One server (Centos 7) in this case, requires acceptance of the EULA for the MS odbc driver.  I have seen how to do this on an install, but have not been able to make it work with update.

```
 tasks:
    - name: update OS
      dnf:
    name: '*'
        state: latest
```

I have tried adding an environment variable with no success.  Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: In what way did you try to add an environment variable? What variable, what value? In what way didn't it work, did you see any change? Please add more detail.

Comment: I added an environment block with ACCEPT_EULA: 'y' to the task.  It did not fail, but it did not work either

Comment: @KevinNelson: please don't add this info in  a comment, edit your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According [Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (Linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and the tag `centos7`.

```
tasks:

  - name: Update OS
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    yum:
      name: '*'
      state: latest
```